# How to prevent SSL Proxying for https site?

Tags: api, security, nginx, proxy, ssl-certificate

I'm serving my site through nginx. For securing it, I have added ssl certificate and made it compatible with https protocol.
Now when I do request data from the site through browser while keeping ssl proxying on, whole request body and response body are showing there, so there is some loophole in my configuration and if it's not a loophole, I want it to be like giant company's site - facebook, apple etc. Where these ssl proxy tool can not parse the request and response.

Answer (score 0):

If the client doesnt explicit show itself as a proxy (aka via `X-Forwarded`  headers), is very hard to know for a server if any connection establishes proxied, Of course, out there are sophisticated methods to find these connections, like blacklists with common proxy sites, AI traffic algorithms, etc. but you will need massive amounts of data (that giant companies have) or specialized traffic services like cloudflare.